# Identify columns applicable for percentage text to decimal conversion

Tags: r, import

My imported data comes with varying row/col size. I need to convert text % (32%) into decimal (0.32). Some columns have the text percentage, others are normal numeric and need to be unchanged.

I can convert the string to decimal across a column, and apply this across the data frame, however no elegant way of selectively only applying the conversion to relevant columns. I have solved my problem in a clunky manner by creating a vector to detect columns with % strings and then running a loop across the dataframe checking the vector for which columns to apply this rule. I'm looking for a cleaner solution

```r
# Example structure of data on a small scale
df <- data.frame(desc = c('a','b','c'),val = c(10, 3, 100), perc = c('23.01%', '11.0%','2.33%'))
#   desc val   perc
# 1    a  10 23.01%
# 2    b   3  11.0%
# 3    c 100  2.33%

# the below converts everything which is not desired
sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%","",x))/100)
#      desc  val   perc
# [1,]   NA 0.10 0.2301
# [2,]   NA 0.03 0.1100
# [3,]   NA 1.00 0.0233

# my (clunky) solution
aa <- rep(0,ncol(df))
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){aa[i] <- length(grep("%",df[,i]))}
# [1] 0 0 3
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){if (aa[i]>0) {df[,i] <- as.numeric(sub("%", "",df[,i],fixed=TRUE))/100 } }
#  desc val   perc
# 1    a  10 0.2301
# 2    b   3 0.1100
# 3    c 100 0.0233
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution would be the following:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_if(~sum(str_detect(., "%")) > 0, 
            ~as.numeric(str_remove(., "%")) / 100)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, although it introduced **NA** in the % columns where the field is **blank** (to be fair, the sample data I provided did not fully imitate all the potential obstacles in structure of my actual data). This does not present a problem though as I can strip them out when writing the file. I imagine the sum check could be expanded to ignore blanks when handling?

Comment: No, `~sum(str_detect(., "%")) > 0` just checks if there are any elements containing `%` for each variable. Blank means an empty string? If you only want complete observations, you could use `filter()` with `complete.cases()`: `df  %>% 
  mutate_if(~sum(str_detect(., "%")) > 0, 
            ~as.numeric(str_remove(., "%")) / 100) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))`

Comment: I need to keep all records (rows). The problem is that the columns with % values also have blank fields. See updated sample data, my apologies for not doing so in the original example.     df <- data.frame(desc = c('a','b','c'),val = c(10, 3, 100), perc = c('23.01%', '','2.33%'))

Comment: Ideally, remain as presented - a blank. But as I said, the solution works, and it's very clean and simple - perfectly usable, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is find columns that have a %, convert them to character (just so you don't have to work with factors which are PITA in this case) and remove % signs and divide numbers by 100.

```
xy <- data.frame(desc = c('a','b','c'),val = c(10, 3, 100), perc = c('23.01%', '11.0%','2.33%'))

# find which colums have a % - this assumes % is used only to denote percentages
perc.index <- sapply(xy, grepl, pattern = "%")
# convert columns that have at least one % to character
# this step can be also done manually or on import (stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy[, colSums(perc.index) > 0] <- sapply(xy[, colSums(perc.index) > 0, drop = FALSE], as.character)
xy[perc.index] <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", xy[perc.index])) / 100
xy

  desc val   perc
1    a  10 0.2301
2    b   3   0.11
3    c 100 0.0233
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfectly. Both my method and the tidyverse solution generated 25 warnings on my actual data, but this did not

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp=nchar(as.character(df$perc))
tmp2=which(substr(df$perc,tmp,tmp)=="%")
tmp3=which(!substr(df$perc,tmp,tmp)=="%")

df$perc2=NA
df$perc2[tmp2]=as.numeric(gsub("%","",df$perc[tmp2]))/100
df$perc2[tmp3]=as.numeric(as.character(df$perc[tmp3]))
```